# How to create a stage fill with tabs?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I tested this code to create a stage with tabs:

```
public void GeneralConfiguration()

    {



        Stage configurationStage = new Stage();

        configurationStage.setTitle("General Settings");

        configurationStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);



        Group grid = new Group();



        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();



        //Create Tabs

        Tab tabA = new Tab();

        tabA.setText("Main Component");

        tabA.setClosable(false); // da se mahne opciqta da se zatvarq tab

        //Add something in Tab

        StackPane tabA_stack = new StackPane();

        tabA_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        tabA_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab A")); // dobavq se tuka accordion

        tabA.setContent(tabA_stack);

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);



        Tab tabB = new Tab();

        tabB.setText("Second Component");

        tabB.setClosable(false); // da se mahne opciqta da se zatvarq tab

        //Add something in Tab

        StackPane tabB_stack = new StackPane();

        tabB_stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        tabB_stack.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab B"));

        tabB.setContent(tabB_stack);

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabB);



        Tab tabC = new Tab();

        tabC.setText("Last Component");

        tabC.setClosable(false); // da se mahne opciqta da se zatvarq tab

        //Add something in Tab

        StackPane tabC_vBox = new StackPane();

        tabC_vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        tabC_vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label@Tab C"));

        tabC.setContent(tabC_vBox);

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabC);



        //grid.add(tabPane);

        grid.getChildren().add(tabPane);



        // Configure dialog size and background color

        Scene Scene = new Scene(grid, 800, 600, Color.WHITESMOKE);

        configurationStage.setScene(Scene);

        configurationStage.show();



    }
```

Can you tell me how I can fill the stage with the tabs body. Now I get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the tab pane into a grid. You can put it directly into the scene like:

```
Scene Scene = new Scene(tabPane, 800, 600, Color.WHITESMOKE);
```

[image: Scene with all the tab pane]

And now you have all the tab pane adjusted to the size of the scene.

Hope it helps!